# Laravel 5.6 - Reset Password Tokens how to ensure they match?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

When a user forgets their password and try to reset it, they get a reset password email link with a token:

`site.com/my/password/reset/ddc3669ab1bbd78abe620ef910716ae91678bb4beb5cd8896e21efaaa0c9d5c6`

On the backend though, the token in the database `password_resets` table looks like it's hashed:
`$2y$10$O6pgU21FhsOcgpgeqR8RReFYoCGhHNBH5bHKxtE6q1tJMTUufrbr.`

So when the route is visited, the only piece of identifying information passed is the token:
`ddc3669ab1bbd78abe620ef910716ae91678bb4beb5cd8896e21efaaa0c9d5c6`

```php
// Controller Method
passwordResetVerifyByToken($token){
  $record = DB::table('password_resets')->where('token', $token)
                                        ->first();
}
```

Ofcourse we won't get a record, as the plain token from the email will NOT match the hashed one in the database with the above query. So with the plain emailed token link, when the user clicks it, how can we compare it to the one in the database to verify it exists and is a matching token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Hash::check` method, which will return true or false depending of if the hash of the reset token matches the stored database value.

```php
if (Hash::check($token, $row->token)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Laravel docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing#basic-usage

Comment: Right, but how do we pull out the `$row->token` (since the only thing in the email link is the token itself, what would the `$row` query look like)?

Comment: If you are using the standard laravel auth controllers, `email` will be one of the query string params sent in the email: https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/Notifications/ResetPassword.php#L62

Comment: Ah gotcha, so now we can just use the email to identify the record and compare tokens. I had a custom email and seemed to miss the email part, thank you so much for pointing that out in the github link!

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry Laravel Have there own advanced function Hash you should try this

```
if (Hash::check($token, $row->token)) {
  // write your code or other function 
 }
```